# Ethereum hard-fork: Geth Syncing Issue

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, hardforks

I have been running a geth testnet instance for the last 2 months and learning this. But after the hard-fork i have seen the syncing to be extremely slow. I updated geth to ***Version: 1.7.0-stable***.

eth.syncing shows:

```
{
  currentBlock: 1701957,
  highestBlock: 1711644,
  knownStates: 0,
  pulledStates: 0,
  startingBlock: 1699999
}
```

I am still behind < 10,000 blocks. Is there anything else I need to to do apart from updating geth to latest. Any help, would be appreciated. :)

Comment: What hardware do you use for this node?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35282)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by removing the `--bootnodes` flag when starting geth. This was the bottleneck, as when I removed this statement and restarted geth, all the syncing started happening at a good pace.

Comment: Could you please accept this answer to prevent community to bump this question up again and again?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use geth flag `--syncmode "fast"`. This can run the fast syncing mode.